# Microsoft FTP fails to connect after the client requests the list of features (FEAT)

Tags: iis, ftp, timeout

This is a really weird problem. The first few times I try to connect FileZilla just hangs on the line `211-Extended features supported:` for a while before coming up and saying Error: Could not connect to server. The FileZilla log below:

```
Command:    PASS ***********
Response:   230 User logged in.
Command:    FEAT
Response:   211-Extended features supported:
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

The weird thing is if I keep trying to connect eventually it just works and connects fine. After FileZilla knows which features the server supports it stops asking for a while which enables you to connect first time until FileZilla decides it wants to double check the features list again. I'm at a loss on how to debug this.

Has anyone experienced similar?

Comment: Update: I get a very similar problem when using SmartFTP. 
[12:20:39] PASS (hidden)
[12:20:39] 230 User logged in.
[12:20:39] SYST
[12:20:39] 215 Windows_NT
[12:20:39] Detected Server Type: Windows NT
[12:20:39] RTT: 34.292 ms
[12:20:39] FEAT
[12:20:39] 211-Extended features supported:
[12:20:58] Server closed connection
[12:20:58] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.
[12:20:58] Connect failed. Waiting to retry (30s)...

Comment: This fixed the issue for me: http://serverfault.com/questions/163362/microsoft-ftp-fails-to-connect-after-the-client-requests-the-list-of-features-fe/207230#207230

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem using FTP for IIS with FileZilla and other clients. The root cause is still a mystery to me. However, if you manage the server, a workaround is to disallow the FEAT command.

For IIS 7.5: IIS Manager -> FTP Request Filtering -> Deny Command

I cannot advise regarding earlier IIS versions.

The server will then respond to FEAT with "500 'FEAT': command not allowed". FileZilla handles this gracefully and goes on to complete the connection.

Answer (score -1):

The FEAT command is part of new FTP protocol extension implemented in IIS 7 / 7.5 to allow hosting of multiple FTP with same IP / Port.
See: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robert_mcmurray/archive/2007/08/28/virtual-hosts-and-host-names-in-ftp7.aspx

Comment: Already answered by Brent - almost 1 year ago..